# Updating Java on Linux

Tags: rpm, java, scientific-linux

My machine currently has:

```
[support@turndownForWhat sbin]$ java -version
java version "1.5.0_10"
```

I would like to know if there is any way possible to install/extract java 1.7 to a specific directory and NOT update 1.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to have several different java versions installed. By convention in Linux, software packages that aren't available through your package manager are usually installed under `/opt` or `/usr/local/`.

Just download Java 1.7 from Oracle and extract it to one of those locations. Then set your `PATH` or `JAVA_HOME` to include that location, depending on your use.

On Debian, you have a utility called `update-java-alternatives` that will allow you to set the default Java version. It seems you can do that with the `alternatives` command in SL as described in [this forum post](http://scientificlinuxforum.org/index.php?showtopic=596).

Comment: Off topic but I can also modify the POM file in my java project to include Java 1.7 JDK...

Comment: @ryekayo Yes, that's off-topic here. Try googling maven-compiler-plugin and you'll get answers.

Comment: would you be able to possibly provide how I can set only one project to run on Java 1.7